# How to control the permissions of a mounted usb drive?

Tags: usb, mount, permissions, chmod

I have multiple USB drives, used for different purposes, and I've noticed they have different permissions when mounted, and, moreover, a chmod command has no effect. Why is this and is there a workaround to get the desired permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mount the USB drives you can specify the owner and the group with options `uid` and `gid`. For example:

```
$ sudo mount -o uid=1000,gid=1000 /dev/sdX /path/to/mountpoint
```

If you want to change permissions you can add the `umask` option too:

```
$ sudo mount -o uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022 /dev/sdX /path/to/mountpoint
```

`umask=022` will set the Owner to *read, write, execute*. Group and Others will have *read, execute*.

You can read more about `umask` here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Umask

Answer (score 0):

Your USB drive is formatted as an NTFS (i.e. windows) volume. mount assumes the files are owned by some windows user. You don't have a user mapping file (see `man ntfs-3g`, `man ntfs-3g.usermap`), so mount figures there's no point in managing the ownership and permissions, so it just sets them to whatever you tell it to (or whatever the default is).

If you pass `-o permissions`, chmod should work.